# Возобновить id при удаление

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Я работаю с базой данной MySQL и хочу, чтобы при удалении человека с Id 27 все Id возобновились и снова шли по порядку

Comment: Т.е., например, у вас есть юзеры с id: 1, 2, 3, 4. Вы удалили 2 и хотите, чтобы 3-й стал 2-м, 4-й стал 3-им, и следующий новый юзер уже был с id = 4?

Comment: Не надо этого делать. Если требуется непрерывная нумерация - добавьте для этих целей ещё одно поле.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, так делать не стоит. Айдишник у сущности никогда не должен меняться. Если он один раз присвоен, то таким он должен остаться навсегда. Иначе вы сделаете себе большое количество серьёзных трудноотлаживаемых проблем.

Во-вторых, считается хорошей практикой подобные сущности не удалять физически из бызы, а только делать некоторую пометку, что он удалён (например, завести колонку deleted, в которую при удалении проставлять "1" или дату-время удаления)

Comment: *Айдишник у сущности никогда не должен меняться.* У экземпляра сущности. И главное добавление - даже если этот экземпляр удалён.